# PostgreSQL view return very slow result in group by

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have 10 tables having same columns.I made separate data for year wise like `2011,2012 .. 2020`.

I made one view for combine all the tables data using union all.

```
    create view as a combine
    select * from table_2011
    union all
    select * from table_2012
    ..
    union all 
    select * from table_2020;
```

Now when I run some query which having group by its taking 9 Minutes to return data.

```
    select name, count(name) from combine group by name;
```

Can any one help me how to improve speed of view? I already give index to all the tables and columns.

[image: analysed select]

Comment: please, attach a result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT name, count(), ...

Comment: I added result of result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT

Comment: You sent EXPLAIN only (you should to write ANALYZE too). Please, don't use screenshots. There is good tool for sharing plans https://explain.depesz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add Index to name column on your view